# Confusing results performance test Java 1.8 Collection Api

Tags: java, performance, collections, arraylist, java-8

i am playing around with java 1.8.
I read that the new collection api works faster because 
it runs the operations on the data structures parallelized.

I want to see this efford. 
So i wrote following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<SamplePerson> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        persons.add(new SamplePerson(EyeColour.BLUE,20,"Max Musterman",Gender.MALE));
    }

    long nsBefore = System.nanoTime();


    // using the new collection api - parallel way??
    persons.forEach(samplePerson -> samplePerson.setAge(22));

    //  sequential way
    for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++){
        persons.get(i).setAge(22);
    }

    long nsAfter = System.nanoTime();

    long runtime = nsAfter - nsBefore;

    System.out.println("Time in Nanoseconds: " + runtime);      
}
```

My Processor: i7-2600 CPU

Result using the "parallel" way: 
Time in Nanoseconds: 74836825

Result using the sequential way:
Time in Nanoseconds: 45071315

Could everybody explain this results.
Is the overhead to set up this threats that high? 
I am a bit confused please help me :-)

Comment: Please show your sequential code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). I mean: Benchmarking in Java is hard and naive approaches are deemed to fail.

Comment: By the way, the default implementation of `forEach()` (as well as the `ArrayList` implementation) is just a regular for-each loop, so (as pointed out below) it probably isn't parallel.

Comment: at Jigar Joshi: thank you for that quick respons. 
That seems to be the solution. 
Now i used the parallel Stream and initiated a warmup phase (i ran a bunch of loops before measuring).

Results: 

Result using the parallel way: Time in Nanoseconds: 41721340.
Result using the sequential way: Time in Nanoseconds: 43841863

at maaartinus: I noticed that benchmarking in java isn't as easy as i thought.So i guess that this measuring isn't very representiv at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to consider JIT warmup while benchmarking something, I would let it run first time and in second iteration benchmark the same thing in this case

also you are not using parallelStream you need

```
persons.parallelStream().forEach()
```

Comment: Even the "run it a few times" advice here is too naive to give you real performance numbers.  You need to use a real performance framework like JMH for measurement.